# Ternary Operators in Scala

Tags: scala, if-statement, ternary-operator

I would like to simplify this:

```
var countA: Int = 0
var countB: Int = 0

if (validItem) {
  if (region.equalsIgnoreCase( "US" )) {
    if (itemList > 0) {
      countB = 1
    } else {
      countA = 1
    }
  } else {
    countB = 1
  }
} else {
  countA = 1
}
```

How do I use ternary operator in scala.

Comment: Does this even compile? How can one `if` have three `else`?

Comment: I think it's just a copy-paste mess. Probably OP is asking "how to write `if (itemList > 0) { countB = 1 } else { countA = 1 }` in one statement?". Anyway the question has very low quality and will be likely closed if not improved.

Comment: @Thilo Sorry Updated.

Comment: @laughedelic updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This might be a bit confusing for a "newbie", but you could attach a ternary method to the `Boolean` class like so.

```
implicit class Ternary[T](condition: Boolean) {
  def ??(a: => T, b: => T): T = if (condition) a else b
}
```

Usage:

```
(4 == 4)??("yes","no")         // res0: String = yes
("abc".length < 2).??(1,0)     // res1: Int = 0
List('c').isEmpty.??('X','+')  // res2: Char = +
```

Comment: This helps to define something that _looks like_ ternary operator, but I think it doesn't really help to simplify the code in the OP's example.

Comment: @laughedelic, yeah I put this up before the OP had a compilable example. I assumed that the title was correct and a ternary operator was the goal.  I see now that the example code is more complicated, and yet my answer was accepted. Go figure.  I think the OP is confused on a number of fronts. I still don't know what "1.5" is supposed to be.

Comment: Right (I didn't downvote your answer). Another thing: in your definition `??`'s arguments should be lazy.

Comment: @laughedelic, agreed.

Answer (score 20):

You should not need to use a ternary operator in Scala. In Scala, `if` is an expression not a statement, you can say `val x = if (b) 1 else 2`.

The usage of `var` in your example also points to a problem, because you can usually avoid this when you use the `if` as an expression.

Let's try to break down the code to avoid the `var`, i.e. first remove all `if` statements that are not expressions with a corresponding `else` and always provide both values:

```
var countA: Int = ???
var countB: Int = ???

if (validItem) {
  if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("US")) {
    if (itemList > 0) {
      countA = 0
      countB = 1
    } else {
      countA = 1
      countB = 0
    }
  } else {
    countA = 0
    countB = 1
  }
} else {
  countA = 1
  countB = 0
}
```

Now we can define the condition for which either of `countA` and `countB` is one:

```
val isUS     = region.equalsIgnoreCase("US")
val hasItems = itemList > 0
val isA      = !validItem || (isUS && !hasItems)
val isB      = !isA
// or: val isB = validItem && (!isUS || hasItems)
```

and then:

```
val countA   = if (isA) 1 else 0
val countB   = if (isB) 1 else 0
```

Answer (score 10):

I think the short answer is that in Scala there is **no** [`?:` ternary operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:). Although you can imitate the syntax using implicits (see @jwvh's answer), I think it doesn't really simplify anything.

There are a couple of important properties of the conventional `?:`

1. it always has *two branches*
2. following from the previous property, the ternary operator always *returns a value* (this is mostly the point of using `?:`)

   ```
   val result: Int = if (true) 1 else 2
   // result is 1
   ```
3. branches are evaluated *lazily*

   ```
   if (true) 1 else (0/0) // returns 1
   if (false) 0/0 else 2  // returns 2
   // i.e. 0/0 is not evaluated
   ```

As you see, in Scala `if-else` (with `else`) construction satisfies these properties. This is not the case for `if-else` construction in some other languages, like C or Java, because it doesn't return a value.

So the bottom line is that in `Scala` you don't need a ternary operator, because you can just use `if-else`.

**UPDATE**

As Alexey Romanov mentions in the comments, `if` statement without `else` actually satisfies the first condition as well. When you write

```
val result = if (true) 1
```

it actually means `if (true) 1 else ()`, so `result` will have type `AnyVal` instead of `Int`, because the return type of the `if` expression is the lowest common bound of the both branches (`Int` and `Unit` in this case).

Comment: `if` without `else` satisfies these properties too: the second branch isn't visible, but it exists and has value `()`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov thanks, I totally forgot about this property of `if`. I'll add it to the answer, because it may lead to unexpected behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on [@0__'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40644224/14955) (if that is his/her real name), you can also use tuples to assign to two variables at once.

```
val (countA, countB) = 
  if (validItem) {
    if (region.equalsIgnoreCase("US")) {
      if (itemList > 0) (0,1) else (1,0)
    } else {
      (0,1)
    }
  } else {
    (1,0)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question and I'm taking a break from a current problem, so I thought I'd leave a basic pattern match solution.

```
val (countA, countB) =
  (validItem, region.equalsIgnoreCase("US"), itemList > 0) match {
    case (true, true, false) | (false, _, _) => (1, 0)
    case _                                   => (0, 1)
  }
```