# Ternary operator usage in Scala program

Tags: scala, filter, ternary-operator

I have a Array of Objects that I need to apply filter.

```
val filteredList = list.filter{ l =>  (pid == "") ? true : l.ProviderId.toUpperCase().contains(pid.toUpperCase()))}
```

This code is not getting complied by Scala compiler. I am getting error like 
1) value ? is not a member of boolean
2) type toUpperCase is not a member of string.

Can anyone please help me how to write this ternary operator inside the filter function in scala.

I agree that I can write a custom function to handle this as mentioned @ [Ternary Operators in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643839/ternary-operators-in-scala) 
However, I am interested in why there is compilation error for this statement.
Because, this is valid statement in Java.

Comment: what is `pid`? you mean `l == ""` ?

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but `if (pid == "") true` is redundant. You could write this expression as `pid == "" || l.ProviderId.toUpperCase().contains(pid.toUpperCase())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ternary Operators in Scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40643839/ternary-operators-in-scala)

Comment: pid is a search parameter I am passing from UI based upon which I need to filter out the list. The || operator is a good solution. But I am interested in why there is a compilation error for this statement in scala. Unfortunately, there are so many dislikes to this question already.

Comment: Scala has no `val x = (a == 0) ? 1 : 2` type of syntax. Why would you even expect it to compile ? You need to do something like `val x = if (a == 0) 1 else 2`

Comment: There's an error because that syntax doesn't exist in Scala. As explained in the answers to the other question, if-else is an expression in Scala, so there is no need for it.

Comment: @SrikantSahu It may be valid in Java but you are not writing Java code.  Scala just doesn't have that syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is that Scala does not support the ternary operator you described. That is supported Java but there's no need for it in Scala.

In Java the main difference between the `if` **statement** and the ternary operator is that the latter is an expression, meaning that it's evaluated to a result, while `if` is (as I previously suggested) a statement that relies on side-effects within its scope to make things happen.

In Scala `if` is already an expression, hence there is no need for a ternary operator.

Your code would be structured as follows:

```
val filteredList = list.filter { l => if (pid == "") true else l.ProviderId.toUpperCase().contains(pid.toUpperCase()) }
```

As suggested in a comment you can further improve the readability by not relying on `if`s to express simple boolean conditions.

```
val filteredList = list.filter { l => pid == "" || l.ProviderId.toUpperCase().contains(pid.toUpperCase())) }
```

Furthermore, in your case, `pid` seems to be external to the list itself, so maybe pulling it out of the `filter` (which has *O(n)* complexity on `List`) can save you some cycles:

```
val filteredList = if (pid.isEmpty) list else list.filter(_.ProviderId.toUpperCase().contains(pid.toUpperCase()))
```

It also looks like you are trying to make a case-insensive equality check on the two string, in which case you may be interested in using a `Pattern` and not converting `pid` to upper case at every loop:

```
val pidPattern = Pattern.compile(Pattern.quote(pid), Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)

val filteredList = if (pid.isEmpty) list else list.filter(l => pidPattern.matcher(l.ProviderId).find)
```

Comment: Thanks stefanobaghino for pointing out the best practices and the way to code this properly.